# How to hide/remove featured images in particular categories post?

Tags: categories, post-thumbnails

I have multiple posts in three categories.
The categories are
1. News
2. Images
3. **Videos**

If i click any post that Post's Feature image was shown in top of the article. But other two categories is ok but in **Videos** category i dont want to display feature images. Is there any way to do this..

(Note: I am setting feature images for videos category because i am using that image in different place. So i cant remove this. So tell some solution to hide image when viewing post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that all your posts are come from single.php. WordPress provides has_category() function to check if post has specific category.

So your code on single.php will need to be like something in given below

```
if( !has_category('video') ){
   the_post_thumbnail();
}
```

where it checks if post has 'video' category. And if it is false then the feature image will be displayed. otherwise, it can't. Hope it will be help you.

Comment: Thanks but i found other solution through css:                                .category-videos .post-image.single{display:none;}